# Nativescript Vue: Is there a way to ease in components rather than an abrupt show/hide?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have been using `v-show` but there are some components where it just doesn't feel right to do.  It's a jarring experience to have an abrupt show or an abrupt hide of a component.  Is there any way in NS Vue to do this smoother?  I know `transition` doesn't support `height`, which would have been a good solution so I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Why would you need it to have height? What is the element you want to have a transition? Please provide a more accurate description about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the Vue wrapper `transition`:

```html
<transition name="fade">
    <Label class="my-label" v-show="show">hello</Label>
</transition>
```

And in the `css` file or snippet you can add

```css
.my-label {
    height: 80; // or whatever height you want it to have
}
```

Comment: whoa, Vue Transitions work with Nativescript Vue?  Do I need to import anything or do they just work out of the box?

Comment: I think you don't have to import anything. Check out this article https://nativescripting.com/posts/nativescript-vue-transitions.

Comment: When the Label fades out, it is still taking the space in the view/layout.
This does not happen when transition is not applied.
Any ideas/workarounds for this?